# Looping Issue with VBA Macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am writing a macro that gets data from two separate locations and pastes it into a template, saves the template as a new file, then loops back and repeats the process. The macro works for one file but fails when looping. Specifically, the computer can't find the file and thinks it has been moved or deleted.

Here is the code:

'sub and dims excluded to save space

```
'set folder locations
dataFolder = "C:\Location\" 'abbreviated
previousFolder = "C:\Other Location\" 'abbreviated

'set file names
dataFile = Dir(dataFolder & "*.xls*")
previousFile = Dir(previousFolder & "*.xls*")

Do While dataFile <> ""

    Set dataWB = Workbooks.Open(dataFolder & dataFile)'this is where the code breaks on looping
    
        'the contents of the loop work fine on the first go so I am excluding them
    
    'Save file to directory
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\Save Location\") 
            
'how I am ending the loop
dataFile = Dir
previousFile = Dir

Loop
```

End Sub`

I hope this is sufficiently clear. To be even more concise:

```
dataFile = Dir(dataFolder & "*.xls*")
previousFile = Dir(previousFolder & "*.xls*")

Do While dataFile <> "" 'breaks here after succeeding with first file

'stuff to do

dataFile = Dir
previousFile = Dir

Loop
```

I was expecting the program to grab the next file in the source folder and repeat the process but instead it breaks saying it can't find the next file (even though it returns the files name in that error message).

Comment: What is `previousFile` doing ? You can't iterate 2 different folders simultaneously. What is the connection between the 2 files, are they named the same ?

Comment: You can only have one `Dir()` loop in progress, so your nested loop using two `Dir()` can't work.   Also the concept of "next file" is not strictly defined when using Dir(), so if you need pairs of matching files that's not guaranteed.

Comment: @CDP1802 Thank you for helping me understand the constraints I am working with. I am pulling data from two separate workbooks (previousFile and dataFile) and then pasting the data into my template. I am not sure how else I might go about handling the fact that I am pulling data from two different sources over the course of one loop, but I will give it some thought.

Comment: @TimWilliams I was unaware of that constraint. Thank you for pointing it out. Any suggestions on how I might otherwise go about working with pairs of matching files? 

-edit-

Just saw the code you posted. I will have a look, thanks.

Comment: For "pairs of files" you'd need to explain exactly how the files are "paired" (same or similar name, or something else)

Comment: @TimWilliams I figured I'd need a good naming convention to make pairs of files work. For context, I manage development data for an insurance company. Each of our programs gives us quarterly triangles. I am importing data from the most recent quarter (dataFile in my code) and development factors from the previous quarter (previousFile) to an analysis template. Once that is done I save the template as a new document, set it aside, and then repeat the process with the next program. I'll be working on the problem for a few hours this morning and will update this thread with my progress.

Answer (score 0):

If you push the file loop out into a separate function it's easier to deal with multiple file locations:

```vb
Sub tester()
    Dim files As Collection, filesPrev As Collection
    
    Set files = MatchedFiles("C:\Temp\", "*.xls*")
    Set filesPrev = MatchedFiles("C:\Temp\Previous\", "*.xls*")
    
    Debug.Print files.Count, filesPrev.Count
    
    'do something with file names in the collections
    
End Sub

'Return a collection of file paths
Function MatchedFiles(ByVal fldr As String, pattern As String) As Collection
    Dim f
    If Right(fldr, 1) <> "\" Then fldr = fldr & "\"
    Set MatchedFiles = New Collection
    f = Dir(fldr & pattern)
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        MatchedFiles.Add fldr & f
        f = Dir()
    Loop
End Function
```